# Bash search order among aliases, functions, binaries

Tags: bash, function, alias

```
function mycmd { echo 'function'; }

# After defining the alias, the function stops being visible, even if redefined.
alias mycmd="echo 'alias'"

# Yet if a binary is found in $PATH, it hides both.
echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash" > mycmd
echo "echo 'file'" >> mycmd
chmod +x mycmd
export PATH=$(pwd):"$PATH"
```

Are those observations correct and reliable? What are the intended benefits of such shadowing rules?

Comment: Possibly related Unix & Linux question - [Order of executables started in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132623/order-of-executables-started-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precedence rules are not spelled out anywhere in `man bash` as far as I can see, but the list of types in the manual are according to the precedence:

> ```
> type [-aftpP] name [name ...]
>        With no options, indicate how each name would be interpreted  if
>        used as a command name.  If the -t option is used, type prints a
>        string which is one of alias,  keyword,  function,  builtin,  or
>        file  if  name  is  an  alias,  shell  reserved  word, function,
>        builtin, or disk file, respectively. […]
> ```

The important part is this:

> alias,  shell  reserved  word, function, builtin, or disk file

Answer (score 2):

No — the observation about the script/binary on the PATH is incorrect.

While the alias is in effect, both the script and the function are effectively invisible. See [Command search and execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) and [Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) in the Bash manual.

Basically, the order for simple command names (with no slash in the name) is, from first to last:

- aliases
- functions
- built-ins
- external executables (found via PATH)

You can demonstrate with this adaptation of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function mycmd { echo "function: $*"; }

mycmd should be the function

# After defining the alias, the function stops being visible, even if redefined.
alias mycmd="echo 'alias'"

mycmd should be the alias

# Yet if a binary is found in $PATH, it hides both.
echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash" > mycmd
echo 'echo "file: $*"' >> mycmd
chmod +x mycmd
export PATH=$(pwd):"$PATH"

mycmd should still be the alias

unalias mycmd

mycmd should be the function once more

unset -f mycmd

mycmd should finally be the file
```

I've modified the script and the function to also echo any arguments to the command (and using `$*` instead of `"$@"` is appropriate in this context, though it would certainly be possible to write the code to use `"$@"` instead).

Sample output (script `so43.sh`):

```
$ bash so43.sh
function: should be the function
function: should be the alias
function: should still be the alias
function: should be the function once more
file: should finally be the file
$
```

Why is it the function?  Good question!  By default, aliases don't work within scripts.  They do work interactively.  When I copied my script (minus the shebang) and pasted it to my terminal, I got this output (where `Scafell-Pike JL:` is my prompt):

```
Scafell-Pike JL:     function mycmd { echo "function: $*"; }
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     mycmd should be the function
function: should be the function
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     # After defining the alias, the function stops being visible, even if redefined.
Scafell-Pike JL:     alias mycmd="echo 'alias'"
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     mycmd should be the alias
alias should be the alias
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     # Yet if a binary is found in $PATH, it hides both.
Scafell-Pike JL:     echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash" > mycmd
Scafell-Pike JL:     echo 'echo "file: $*"' >> mycmd
Scafell-Pike JL:     chmod +x mycmd
Scafell-Pike JL:     export PATH=$(pwd):"$PATH"
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     mycmd should still be the alias
alias should still be the alias
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     unalias mycmd
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     mycmd should be the function once more
function: should be the function once more
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     unset -f mycmd
Scafell-Pike JL: 
Scafell-Pike JL:     mycmd should finally be the file
file: should finally be the file
Scafell-Pike JL:
```

Now you can see the alias at work.

The section on aliases in the manual (cited near the top) says:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt` (see [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)).

Adding `shopt -s expand_aliases` at the top of the script and rerunning yields:

```
$ bash so43.sh
function: should be the function
alias should be the alias
alias should still be the alias
function: should be the function once more
file: should finally be the file
$
```

Comment: Re "why is it the function?" / "now you can see the alias": [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) also says, "For _almost_ every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions" (emphasis added). The above illustrates why "almost" and not "always."